# Jquery check if array contains substring

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to check if my array `regions` contains part of a string that users submit. In essence, this jquery script should check if the city that a user included in their address is one of the cities in the `regions` array.

For example, when a user enters `Examplestreet 24 City1` and `City1` is in the `regions` array, it should display a price of `€40`, else it should show `€2/km`.

I have the following code:

```
var regions = ["city1", "city2", "city3"];
var str = $("#addressField").val();
var address = str.toLowerCase();
var key, value, result;
for (key in regions) {
    if (regions.hasOwnProperty(key) && !isNaN(parseInt(key, 10))) {
        value = regions[key];
        if (value.substring() === address) {
            $("#deliveryPrice").text("€40");
        }
        else {
            $("#deliveryPrice").text("€2/km");
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working fine when the string is just the city without the street or other characters, but it should also work if someone enters their full address. So I need to change my code so it searches the array `regions` for any part of the string `address`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regexp to find the right price:

```js
var regions = ["city1", "city2", "city3"];
var address = "example address 42-200 City1 Poland";
var address2 = "city3";
var address3 = "city6";

function priceForAddress(address, regions) {
  var city = regions.find(function (region) {
    var reg = new RegExp(region, 'i');
    return address.match(reg) !== null;
  });
  
  if (city) {
    return '20$';
  } else {
    return '4$/km';
  }
}

console.log(priceForAddress(address, regions));
console.log(priceForAddress(address2, regions));
console.log(priceForAddress(address3, regions));
```

Comment: This is perfect and solved my problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should just find if one of the cities is inside the string using `indexOf`

```js
function test()
{
  var regions = ["city1", "city2", "city3"];
  var str = "Examplestreet 24 City1";
  var address = str.toLowerCase();
  var value, result;
  for (value of regions) {
      result = str.toLowerCase().indexOf(value);
      console.log(result); 
      if (result !== -1)
      {
        console.log("$40");
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("$2/km");
        return;
      }
  }
}

test();
```